# How to access a function within a namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, function, namespaces

Please I am facing a problem while accessing a function within a class inside a namespace in C#.

The format that i know is as follows: `namespace.classname.functionname();`

However, the above method is reporting for me the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property "namespace.classname.functionname()".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to declare an instance of the Class that contains the function

```
namespace.classname YourClass = new namespace.classname();
```

then you can use the function as follows

```
YourClass.functionname();
```

If you want to be able to use the function without declaring an instance of the class it needs to be a static funciton.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of your object first if it's not a static method - your code will end up looking like this:

namespace.classname VARIABLENAME = new namespace.classname(CONSTRUCTOR ARGUMENTS)
VARIABLENANME.functionname()